# Mysterious Display & Edit form customization?

Tags: infopath, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-2016

I have a custom list in O365, with 2 content types. Displaying/editing items of one content type shows a custom display/edit form, items of the other content type does not.

I did not create this site or list, so I'm trying to figure out how the customizations are done.

- I don't see any InfoPath templates in the folders of the list.
- SharePoint Designer is showing the DispForm.aspx and EditForm.aspx as
  "Default".
- I see no form links, when looking at the content types    themselves.

What other customizations are possible, where am I not looking?

Thanks

-John

Answer (score 0):

If you have the right permission level, you should be able to go into the list settings, Advanced Settings and select Yes to allow management of content types. Then once you are in the List Settings, you can see the content types available on that list and click into them to view what edits were done there. Normally, most people will hide certain questions or reorder how they are displayed.